# Create a web application from a preexisting application

Tags: java, swing, tomcat, deployment, web

Is there a way to make a website from a preexisting Swing Java application? I have been looking through different methods for creating a Java web application and created a simple web app using a Tomcat server and Eclipse Web Tools Platform. Will I have to rewrite my app to host it on a Tomcat server or is there an easier way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..I am using a GUI with swing

Then don't convert it, simply<sup>1</sup> deploy the GUI direct from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix. There is more information on [depolying a JWS Application here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html) and also [using a tomcat server with JWS here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/200515/JNLP-Web-Start/java/Java-Web-Start-Tomcat)

1. Or at least, a lot more simply than converting it to a web app.

Comment: This looks a lot more promising thank you

Answer (score 2):

You first need to understand the difference between a web-app and a java application.

The structure of the applications are completely different.

You can use your existing java application but you have to write a lot of code and also you need to find out which web framework([MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) is suitable for you.

1. [Struts 2](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/)
2. [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

etc.

The web application is identified by [web.xml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_descriptor) which will define your web-application. Then you have to write the controllers to handle your incoming request from a browser.

Also you need to create views (jsp, html, jsf etc) to render the response generated from your application.

You can reuse your code to implement the functionality, but you have to define the controllers and views to complete  you application.

I suggest you to read some [web-framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework).

Comment: Looks like Ive got a lot to learn, thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is a broad question.

options could include:

1. use web service to expose your method (restful), tomcat 7 supports it, this way you can reuse your business logic.
2. pick a MVC framework, there are many of them available for you, you can also reuse you business logic with code wrap aroud it.

hope it helps